# PHP If/ELSE or Switch/Case Statement

Tags: php, algorithm, switch-statement

I have give inputs which can be either 1 or 0

```
$no_required
$on_arrival
$schengen_visa
$uk_visa
$usa_visa
```

I have the Following Cases and i want to display unique message back to the user for each one of them

```
a b c d e
1 0 0 0 0   No Visa Required
0 1 0 0 0   Visa can be obtained on Arrival
0 0 1 0 0   You need Schengen Visa
0 0 0 1 0   You need UK visa
0 0 0 0 1   You need US visa
0 0 1 1 1   You need Either of the Visas
0 0 1 1 0   You need Schengen/UK visa
0 0 1 0 1   You need Schengen/US visa
0 0 0 1 1   You need USA/UK visa
```

Where A B C D E F are the above variables. Which is the best and optimized way to display the results.

Comment: How are you storing the data in your code, how about some code? (didnt mean to put this as answer)

Comment: @dirt its basically coming from the database.

Comment: Add the values up as binary values then run the switch on the addition, if my brain is working right there can't be two values the same. ie if a is 1 add to a variable total 1 if b is 1 add 2, if c is one add 4 then do your switch based on the value of total

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php
$messages = array('10000' => 'No Visa Required', '01000' => 'Visa can be obtained on Arrival');
$no_required = '0';
$on_arrival = '1';
$schengen_visa = '0';
$uk_visa = '0';
$usa_visa = '0';

$result = "$no_required$on_arrival$schengen_visa$uk_visa$usa_visa";
if(array_key_exists($result, $messages)){
 echo $messages[$result]; //Visa can be obtained on Arrival
}

?>
```

Answer (score 17):

The conditions you're showing can very nicely be modeled via bit masks:

```
$messages = [
    16 => 'No Visa Required',
    8  => 'Visa can be obtained ...',
    4  => ...
];
```

You then just have to format your separate variables into a bitmask:

```
$bitmask = ($no_required ? 16 : 0)
         | ($on_arrival  ? 8  : 0)
         | ...;
```

Then just pick the right message:

```
echo $messages[$bitmask];
```

---

Note: use of constants instead of magic numbers is pretty much mandatory here as well, so it'd look like this:

```
define('VISA_NONE',       1);
define('VISA_ON_ARRIVAL', 2);
...

$messages = [
    VISA_NONE         => 'No Visa Required',
    ...,
    VISA_US | VISA_UK => 'You need USA/UK visa'
];

// using multiplication instead of conditionals, as mentioned in the comments
$bitmask = $no_required * VISA_NONE
         | $on_arrival  * VISA_ON_ARRIVAL
         | ...;

echo $messages[$bitmask];
```

---

Wrap the whole thing in an appropriate class and you have yourself a nice, readable, maintainable, reusable piece of business logic:

```
class Visa {

    const NONE       = 1;
    const ON_ARRIVAL = 2;
    ...

    protected $messages = [];

    protected $visa;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->messages = [
            static::NONE            => 'No Visa Required',
            ...,
            static::US | static::UK => 'You need USA/UK visa'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param int  $type    One of the class constants.
     * @param bool $enabled Whether this type of visa is required.
     */
    public function set($type, $enabled) {
        $this->visa = $this->visa | $type * (int)(bool)$enabled;
    }

    public function getMessage() {
        return $this->messages[$this->visa];
    }

}


$visa = new Visa;
$visa->set($visa::NONE,       $no_required);
$visa->set($visa::ON_ARRIVAL, $on_arrival);

echo $visa->getMessage();
```

Comment: Hopefully I will never have to maintain such a mess ;)

Comment: If the values are either 0 or 1, can't you just multiply them by each power of 2? Instead of conditionals.

Comment: @Guy Sure, you could also left shift or do a couple of other tricks. I was going for the most obvious solution for somebody apparently not well versed in binary operations. :)

Comment: @deceze, I see, just wanted to point that out since the OP asked for an optimized solution.

Comment: This is called *overengineering*:)

Comment: @Engineer As opposed to a ton of `switch` cases or `if..else`s? If you replace the magic numbers with constants this is by far the most readable and maintainable solution, beating the `"00101"` strings by a mile. :)

Comment: I'd use map , not switch/case or if/else ;)

Comment: @Engineer What about my update? More readable and maintainable than `"00101"`, no? :P

Comment: @deceze You are talking about maintainability, what if variables can have other than "0" and "1" values?Should I refactor all the logic?))

Comment: @Engineer The variables represent a boolean value, yes or no, a truth table. If they will hold completely different values in the future, *any* on the solutions here need to be changed.

Answer (score 5):

I think switch will be good option:

```
$val=$no_required.$on_arrival.$schengen_visa.$uk_visa.$usa_visa;

switch($val)
{
    case "10000":
        echo "No Visa Required";
        break;
    case "01000"   
        echo "Visa can be obtained on Arrival.";
        break;
    case "00100":
        echo "You need Schengen Visa";
        break;
         .
         .   //Continue to add cases .
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A little tip:

Why don't you convert all those binary numbers into a integer value and then pass them through a switch statement?

```
<?php

    $integer_value = convert_binary_to_integer(a,b,c,d,e);

    // I'm not sure PHP provdies a function to convert binary numbers to integers number:
    // But you can write it yourself. It's pretty easy

    switch($integer_value) {
        case 16: // As the first combination of a,b,c,d,e corresponds to number 16 
             // do the appropriate action
        break;
            // ... and so on
    }
?>
```